# Latest changes to Postman tests doesn't reflect in Newman

Tags: postman, newman

I'm noticing that any changes to tests in Postman isn't reflected when running in Newman.
Example:
In Postman, I change the following text from '200ms' to '100ms'

```
console.log("Hello World!");
      
pm.test("C6 Verify response time is less than 100ms", function () {
        pm.expect(pm.response.responseTime).to.be.below(100);
```

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv5sP.png)

But in Newman, it is still getting '200ms'

```
  GET https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2 [200 OK, 2.06KB, 172ms]
  ┌
  │ 'Hello World!'
  └
  √  C6 Verify response time is less than 200ms
```

[Newman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPlXY.png)

Is there a way to clear the cache or something?
So that Newman gets the latest test changes from Postman?

Comment: Did you save and export the updated collection before re-running it using newman ?

Comment: Ahhh... I could do that. All the while, I have been using the url directly to the collection. But is that the only way around this? To export into json?

Comment: @Timothyyeoh make sure its synced with cloud

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm running the newman command from GitLab. And I want the newman command to directly reference the collection via url.

Comment: @PDHide, just saw your answer below, will explore it.

Comment: Ignore the sync part , you have to update the public url as its not automatically updated . Read the note on that window  screenshot in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postman doesn't store/sync collection and environment with the exported json file. You have to do it manually. Export collection and environment as json file if you want the new changes to get reflected in nemman

[image]

**Update:**

as you are using public url link you have to update the link manually as the link won't get updated automatically:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @PDHide, yes, clicking on the 'Update' button does the trick.